# Adding a border to my HTML div shifts my text

Tags: html, css

I'm recently learning some html/css, and doing a little project to get started on my own. I came across a problem. I added a 1px solid black border to a div and it shifted my text right off of my div's background. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please share the code you already have, it helps us help you!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the property to the div:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

The default value for `box-sizing` is `content-box`, which means that the `width` and `height` are the only things accounted for in a defined height and width.

In contrast, `border-box` makes it so that the `width`, `height`, `padding`, and `border` are all within the specified width and height.

For example, in a `<div>` with `box-sizing: content-box; height: 400px; width: 400px`, the *content* (i.e., the text) would be 400px by 400px. Adding `border` or `padding` would push the content over (as is your case) and make the entire box wider. On the other hand, if you change it to `box-sizing` with the same width and height, then the `400px` would account for all of those size properties (except `margin`).